# Is there a condition for a subshift of finite type to be uniquely ergodic?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems

Are SFTs uniquely ergodic in general, or is there a known necessary and sufficient condition for them to be uniquely ergodic?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! It may be helpful to add some context to your question, in particular some reference to what an SFT is (a link to a definition may suffice).

Comment: By no means as they have lots of periodic points.

Comment: A SFT can be uniquely ergodic - for the silly reason that they can consist of a single periodic orbit: for example in the full binary shift we can take $1$ as forbidden word and we get tha $\{ 0^\infty\}$ is uniquely ergodic SFT, similarly taking $00$ and $11$ as forbidden words we get the period two orbit which is uniquely SFT.

Comment: The comments so far are in one dimension. There *are* some examples of 2d uniquely ergodic SFT (e.g. Robinson, but not Kari-Culik), but I don’t think there’s any nice general condition for it.